# .LoadDataSet does not generate a DataSet Column if no data in column

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I have been searching the web but cannot seem to find an answer to this question.  I'm hoping that someone here can help me with this.

I have the following snippet of code in C# :

```
strCompany = "select * from Company ";
db2.LoadDataSet(db.GetSqlStringCommand(strCompany), ds, "Company");
```

The code will create a `dataSet` for me based on the information in the Company table...no problem.  The problem comes from the fact that one of the columns (i.e.: `Address`) in the `Company` table has no data in it...all of the data in this particular column is `NULL`.

So, when the dataSet is created, this column (i.e.: `Address`) is missing from the `dataSet`.  When I try to generate an Xml document from this `dataSet`, there is no  element in the Xml.

Is there a way to make this `.LoadDataSet` (or some other method) generate data so that there will be an `<Address>` element when I go to create the Xml file?